# derivative of momentum p dotted symbol

Tags: html, utf-8

I need to write the derivative of momentum in HTML with the dot notation;
which is a p with a dot above. I've found the analogous symbols

v̇ q̇

for v and q but not that for p.

Comment: It's a 'combining dot above' which is U+0307 You can add it to any letter. Ḟȯṙ ėẋȧṁṗl̇ė… [though idk how to do that in html, but as you already did it for the first two…]

Comment: I'm on linux it doesn't work for me U+0307

Comment: idk how it works on nix, I'm Mac. I found this - http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Blogs/Productivity-Sauce/How-to-Enter-Unicode-Characters